# Extract multiple elements from each list within list

Tags: python

```
oldlist = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,....30], [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,...30], ...]
```

I need to extract elements [0:5] [8:13] [17:21] of each list within a list to create newlist. What I have so far, but it does not work (just gives me a list of empty lists):

```
newlist = [item[0:5][8:13][17:21] for item in oldlist]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this.

```
newlist = [item[0:5]+item[8:13]+item[17:21] for item in oldlist]
```

`item[0:5][8:13][17:21]` this means to take a slice of `item` from index 0 to 4, which returns a new list of length 5 now take a slice from the returned list from index 8 to 12 which returns an empty list.

```
>>> a
[1, 2, 3]
>>> a[0:2]
[1, 2]
>>> a[0:2][5:15]
[]
```

Why empty is being returned is stated explicitly in the docs. [Click here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-bytearray-buffer-xrange)

> The slice of s from *i* to *j* is defined as the sequence of items with index *k * such that **i <= k < j**. If *i* or *j* is greater than *len(s)*, use **len(s)**. If *i* is omitted or *None*, use **0**. If *j* is omitted or *None*, use **len(s)**. If *i* is greater than or equal to *j*, the ***slice is empty***.

Answer (score 2):

Use `+` to concatenate lists.

```
newlist = [item[0:5] + item[8:13] + item[17:21] for item in oldlist]
```